# Mixing C# and Java languages

Tags: c#, java, android, mixing

My goal is to make an android application, which prints a "hello world" text to logcat from C#. I'm thinking of something like this in C#:

```
using MyLibrary;
namespace Hello
{
    public class HelloWorldClass
    {
        public HelloWorldClass()
        {
            MyLibrary.print("hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

then in eclipse project:

```
import Hello;
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Hello something = new Hello(); // it would print "hello world" to logcat
    }
}
```

how can I create that "MyLibrary"? Any related links, references or something that could help?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. C# and Java have different compilers, different runtime environments. You either need some IPC or link them through native linking, not sure if it will work for Android.

Comment: How else can I "program" in c#, but for android? Logcat is android os log

Comment: what you can do is create a wcf service and consume using Java

Comment: Something like this: http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid

Comment: This is too expensive, I want to make something similar myself if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Mono for Android: http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid
But it has some disadvantages. Main is Extreme memory consumtion (at least two times more memory is consumed) because it starts its own VM.